# How to create a associative array in a range, filled by given value?

Tags: arrays, bash, range

How to create an associative array in a range, every position filled by the same given value ?

What's known or given:

Creating an associative array:

```
declare -A my_array
```

define range of array:

```
ug=-10
og=10
```

Value for filling:

```
filling_value=0
```

Comment: Defining a range of values and filling a 0 array to `n` elements are necessarily conflicting requirements. You could fill an array with 20 elements of value 0, for example `array_fill(20, 0)`, or you could define a range lf values `array_range(-10, 10)` each resulting in different arrays. Which are you interesed in doing?

Comment: @Sherif, a Associative Array with by ug=-10 to og=10 given range=20 elements, every of the 20 elemets, fille by $filling_value given value.

Comment: `unset arr ; declare -A arr ; ug=-10 ; og=10 ; val=666 ; foo="$(eval echo [{$ug..$og}]=$val)" ; echo $foo ; eval arr=( $foo ) ; echo ${arr[-5]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filling_value=0

ug=-10
og=10

unset      my_array
declare -A my_array

for ((i=ug; i<=og; i++))
do
    my_array[${i}]="${filling_value}"
done
```

Results:

```
$ typeset -p my_array
declare -A my_array=([10]="0" [-10]="0" [0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0" [-7]="0" [-6]="0" [-5]="0" [-4]="0" [-3]="0" [-2]="0" [-1]="0" [-9]="0" [-8]="0" )
```

A slight variation that generates the same array:

```
for ((i=ug; i<=og; i++))
do
    my_array+=( [${i}]="${filling_value}" )
done
```